# Not able to get matching values from database

Tags: sql, database

I have a database with two tables outdomain(domain) and uploaddata(username,domain). I have stored the values in them directly from a txt file. Now I want to select the matching data from the two tables. I am executing the following query but this query works only for the data I manually enter in both the tables and not for preexisting data.

```
SELECT outdomain . * 
FROM outdomain
INNER JOIN uploaddata ON ( outdomain.domain = uploaddata.domain );
```

I have no clue! Please help.

UPDATE: The problem is if I match "xyz" in both tables, it matches, but if i match "xyz.com", then it fails to match.
Conclusion is that string after dot(.) prevents the query to match the records!

Comment: Have you (manually) checked if there are similar domains in both tables?

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward. If you don't get any rows, it's because the data doesn't match. Period. What DBMS are you using--Oracle, SQL Server, etc.?

Comment: Walter: Yes
Stefan: Yes

Comment: ErikE: I am using SQL

Answer (score 1):

if you do

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    outdomain.domain AS outDomainValue, 
    uploaddate.domain  AS uploaddateDomainValue 
FROM 
    outdomain
    FULL OUTER  JOIN  uploaddata ON 
      (outdomain.domain = uploaddata.domain );
```

If will show you all matches and orphans, you can then verify if all the data is correct and thus why you inner join isn't matching correctly.

Comment: If there are a lot of rows you can add group_by and add field by field to get a much shorter list.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - I've added a DISTINCT but the GROUP BY will be good if you want counts - thanks for the suggestion